# Can shared data in laravel blade templates be altered?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need a global var shared across my blade templates.  That much seems to work.  However I am unable to change the value of that global during template rendering.

In AppServiceProvider::boot() I am using view()->share('sharedVar',1)

Then in AnyTemplate.blade.php I can access those values, but I can not change them.  So, I can not $sharedVar++ or anything like that.

What kind of 'global' or 'shared()' var should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can not change shared variable from within the blade template. I can suggest you [efriandika/laravel-settings](https://packagist.org/packages/efriandika/laravel-settings).

This will give you ability to store your settings and update them anytime, anywhere.